# How to verify an account using SMS or Call

Tags: web, e-commerce, verify

I am working on an eCommerce website but our client told us to add functionalists like they want to verify an user account by sms or by call.

I don't know how to do this and how many of websites and apps do this.

Do they use any third party services or can we implement it by our won?

If we have to use this service please tell me the name and how much it costs and how to setup?

If there is any alternative please tell em that also.

Moreover I want to use this services for testing also.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some websites/apps build it themselves with SMS / Voice APIs...

Others use a Verification specific API...

With SMS / Voice APIs

1. You'll need to generate a code
2. Send it via the channel you use primarily
3. Set some kind of time delay job (queue, worker, whatever)
4. Send a fallback message should you get no response from the user

With an SMS API, that likely varies per country,there is a solution that allows you to go globally with an API call for a flat fee of 10 cents per verification, NOT per attempt (unsuccessful attempts will not be charged towards your account)

#### Nexmo’s Verify API

1. Make a call to https://api.nexmo.com/verify/json (or /xml)
2. Add parameters: api_key, api_secret, verified number, brand
3. ***Optional parameters:** language, length*

[Take a look at the Nexmo's Verify documentation here!](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/verify)

Verification code should arrive to your phone as an SMS. If you wait a while, you'll also get a phone call, and the code will be read to you. The timing and channels used depends on the type of number, the country, and the carrier.

*Reasons to implement Nexmo's Verify*

- Landline & Mobile Verification
- Failover & Retry Sequences
- Simplicity.. Just make one API call

**Other alternatives**: Enterprises (sign a heavy/clunky contract)

Full disclosure, *I work at Nexmo*